# Dell Latitude E7450 cant write disk encryption password A7 password

Tags: boot, dell, password, encryption

After the upgrade to A7 BIOS on my Dell Latitude E7450 running Ubuntu 15.04 the disk encryption screen is no longer working.
Nothing happens on screen when it prompts me for password to unlock sdb5_crypt.

The option to do then is to hold down the powerbutton so the computer restarts and then boots up and shows the same encryption screen but without any graphical elements (text only).
Then the keyboard works and I can enter the password, unlock the disk and boot as normal.

Tried Dell community but no response, so is this something that needs to be solved by a BIOS upgrade. Or can something be done to fix this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10 made it possible to enter the password without a reboot first to go into console mode.